# My jQuery script is running Slow in Firefox

Tags: jquery, performance, firefox

I know there are many posts like this but of course my script is different so I am wondering if maybe my script is inefficient and could be causing the performance drop. It runs fine in Google Chrome.

I am new to jQuery so I thought I have probably done something wrong.

EDIT: Here is a preview of the code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.entry').hover(  
                function() {
                    if (isSorting()) return;
                    $(this).stop().animate({width: '1000px'}, 'fast', function() {
                        var $content = $(this).find('div.content');
                        $content.stop().animate({width: '1000px'}, {duration: 'fast', queue: 'global'});
                        $content.slideDown('normal');
                    });
                },
                function() {
                    if (isSorting()) return;
                    $(this).stop().animate({width: '700px'}, 'fast', function() {
                        var $content = $(this).find('div.content');
                        $content.stop().animate({width: '700px'}, {duration: 'fast', queue: 'global'});
                        $content.slideUp('normal');
                    });
                }
            );
        });
```

I cannot post the real thing due to it being so closely connected to the companies system but it turns out that it is not my code's fault and was the system I had to embed it on. Thank's for the responses!

Comment: what is the purpose of `if (isSorting()) return;` in your code? Is it to prevent run again the same animation if it is already?

Comment: @LelioFaieta no its to control another feature I did not originally post with my code but its inside the jQuery so I thought I had better include it. I have now posted the full thing so you can see how it runs.

Comment: It seems to actually work okay in Firefox like this but in the system I have to add it to it runs slowly so I guess its not my code after all. I will have to keep testing it!

Comment: Are you sure that is jQuery whos run slow? The big part of your code is vanilla JS. I think that the problem is not in the jQuery code.

Comment: In my firefox (MacOS X with Firefox 40) runs OK, without lags or strange timeouts. All runs fluid.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I thought it was the jQuery because only the slideDown and slideUp animations are running slow. Also you're right, it seems to run okay in Stackoverflow, but not on the real live thing on my companies website. Strange but not much I can do then.

Comment: So I think that you have more animations in the same page. All performance being lost in the same time that you increment javascript and layouts. Maybe if we can view a real example is better to debug.

Comment: What I posted it basically it apart from there are additional buttons and data being pulled from the system onto the template you see from the example. The real thing cannot be accessed by the public sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you two things:

1. stop using such selectors `$('div.classname')`. It is very slow in the DOM lookup.
2. use `.dequeue()` method when you use `.queue()`.

---

You can use this:

```
$('.entry').hover(  
    function() {
        if (isSorting()) return;
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '1000px'}, 'fast', function() {
            var $content = $(this).find('.content');
            $content.stop().animate({width: '1000px'}, {duration: 'fast', queue: 'global'});
            $content.slideDown('normal').dequeue();

        });
    },
    function() {
        if (isSorting()) return;
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '700px'}, 'fast', function() {
            var $content = $(this).find('.content');
            $content.stop().animate({width: '700px'}, {duration: 'fast', queue: 'global'});
            $content.slideUp('normal').dequeue();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe div.content would be faster as its helping it find the right thing quicker but that idea is based on nothing. I have no idea how jQuery works behind the scenes.

Comment: @Mayron there is more work it looks for all the divs then goes for the classnames on the all the divs, so that makes it slow in lookup.